# DynamoDB concurrent write, result in throttling

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Below is my structure for table

```
table
    UUID- key - Let call this **EntryKey**
    HistoryLog - this also version number
    Map<UUID (Let call this **EntryChildKey**, BYTE> value
    version - For **optimistic locking**
```

Let's assume map has around 10k entry uuid to some value.

So, my problem is once in while I am getting request to update 10k EntryChildKey(map) value and all this request bombard db at the same time and because, every time I am hitting same EntryKey row, I am running in to lot of concurrency error, version got update every time and I have to retry and all EntryChildKey updates are thrashing each other, **resulting in DynamoDB throttling my request.**

I can get out of this problem if I separate this in to **2 tables as below**, but we have to maintain **HistoryLog** version changing at EntryKey level and also there are some other problem so I can’t take this route

```
Table1                      Table2
    UUID EntryChildKey      UUID EntryKey
    BYTE value              List<UUID> EntryChildKey
```

So, another approach I am thinking is Write ahead log kind of stuff, where I’ll update the version and also record the intent to update the table, but won’t update the record, instead keep it as list in table and then update the EntryChildKey values sequentially. But, I don’t whether there is something like this or similar thing I can do with DynamoDb or not ?

Also any another approach that could help to solve this problem I’ll appreciate

Answer (score 3):

If you really do need to have a version attribute be updated on a single key each time any one of the 10k EntryChild items is updated then your only option is to decouple the table from the update source.

DynamoDB has a hard limit of up to 1000 writes/second to any item at all times. There is simply no way to increase that, for a single item. It doesn't matter what size table you have, how many partitions, or how much total write capacity you allocate to your table, a single item will never be able to be updated more than 1000 times per second.

So, if your requirement to update an attribute (the *HistoryLog* in your example) on the "master" entry item is really firm, then to use DynamoDB your best bet is to introduce a queue and batching to pre-process the updates before writing to Dynamo.

You could create an SQS queue and use a lambda function to read from the queue and write to Dynamo.

In a naive approach, you could simple read from the queue and then write to the table as much as you can, based on the DynamoDB throttling. For 10k updates to the same "master" key this will take at least 10 seconds, though in reality it will likely take longer.

A better option though, would be to run the lambda on a schedule, say once a second, and have it read all the messages available in the queue and combine all updates to the same "master" key into a single update. That way, you only write to the same item at most once every second.

The big challenge with a normal SQS queue is that it does not offer exactly once semantics: meaning there will be items in the queue that will be received multiple times. If you can design a system where you can safely discard duplicate updates then this approach will work wonderful. If not, then things get more complicated.

Comment: Yes solution seems promising but I don't want other dependency on queue for my db.

Comment: Makes sense. Depending on your goals and constraints, DynamoDB may not be right for you. Carefully think about the durability, availability, and consistency requirements of your solution and go with what makes the most sense. DynamoDB is certainly no silver bullet